# Why so much delay from screen touch to onclick event?

Tags: javascript, android, optimization

I have a poor android pad and I'm dev a web app on it. But the delay between screen touching and onClick event in a WebView is longer than 300ms. Is there any way to optimize it?

---

#### Solved:

As max said, it's a delay by design. Fastclick could solve it.

Comment: When you click this webview, is it performing any long running operations that should be placed on another thread?

Comment: Have you looked into [FastClick](https://github.com/ftlabs/fastclick)?

Comment: Please provide some code, it may help find the problem more specifically. But it sounds like you are running too much code on the UI thread and blocking it

Comment: That's just how touch devices work. If you want faster response, definitely look into FastClick as @max suggests.

Comment: Thanks. it solved with fastclick!